# MongoDB Erlang Driver find limit occurs where?

Tags: mongodb, erlang, cursor

I'm trying to integrate MongoDB driver in Erlang.

After some coding it appears to me that the only way to limit the number of retrieved rows can only occurs when dealing with the cursor after the `find()`action.

Here's my code so far :

```
Cursor = mongo:find(Connection, Collection, Selector),
Result = case Limit of
              infinity ->
                 mc_cursor:rest(Cursor);
              _ ->
                 mc_cursor:take(Cursor, Limit)
         end,
mc_cursor:close(Cursor)
```

- What I'm afraid of, is when the Collection will be huge, what will happen ?
- Won't it be to huge to fetch and fit the memory ?
- How the cursor is basically working ?
- Or is there just a better way to limit the fetch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use the `batch_size` parameter.
The following code is from `mongo.erl` file

```
%% @doc Return projection of selected documents starting from Nth document in batches of batchsize.
%%      0 batchsize means default batch size.
%%      Negative batch size means one batch only.
%%      Empty projection means full projection.
-spec find(pid(), collection(), selector(), projector(), skip(), batchsize()) -> cursor(). % Action
find(Connection, Coll, Selector, Projector, Skip, BatchSize) ->
    mc_action_man:read(Connection, #'query'{
        collection = Coll,
        selector = Selector,
        projector = Projector,
        skip = Skip,
        batchsize = BatchSize
    }).
```

===============

reponse to the comments:

In the mc_action_man.erl file, it still use cursor to save "current postion".

```
read(Connection, Request = #'query'{collection = Collection, batchsize = BatchSize} ) ->
    {Cursor, Batch} = mc_connection_man:request(Connection, Request),
    mc_cursor:create(Connection, Collection, Cursor, BatchSize, Batch).
```

In the mc_worker.erl, it is the the data actual send to the db, I think you could add write_log (ex: lager) code to monitor the actual request to find the problem.

```
handle_call(Request, From, State = #state{socket = Socket, ets = Ets, conn_state = CS}) % read requests
    when is_record(Request, 'query'); is_record(Request, getmore) ->
    UpdReq = case is_record(Request, 'query') of
                 true -> Request#'query'{slaveok = CS#conn_state.read_mode =:= slave_ok};
                 false -> Request
             end,
    {ok, Id} = mc_worker_logic:make_request(Socket, CS#conn_state.database, UpdReq),
    inet:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
    RespFun = fun(Response) -> gen_server:reply(From, Response) end,  % save function, which will be called on response
    true = ets:insert_new(Ets, {Id, RespFun}),
    {noreply, State};
```

Comment: You are surely right, although it seems it only batch the number of request on the cursor, once this number reached on the cursor, it probably fetch the next batch... But that was the answer I needed actually. Thanks

Comment: After some investigation it appears that limit and batchsize is clearly not the same thing, of course... Is that because MongoDB Erlang driver is outdated or not complete ?

Comment: In addition, please check your local source code version, and update from github.

Comment: If you would like to update the answer for it to stay the accepted one : `omongo:find("collection", {'$query', {value, <<"10">>}, '$orderby', {'date', -1}, '$maxScan', 5})` This command give the sort with `'$orderby'` and limit with the `'$maxScan'` Options

Comment: I will construct some data in these two days and give you reply, today is Chinese spring festival.

Comment: I haven't use omongo because it is not updated for a long time (more bug) and too simple. Today I have checked mongodb-erlang source-code. there is a "command/2" function and you could put all your complex command there .

Comment: Actually, this is not the "omongo" you know, this is just a module of my own, that pools connection from mongoDB erlang driver, the complex command put is working with mongoDB erlang driver